# ADFS 2.0 single sign-on clarifications

Tags: .net, silverlight, adfs2.0

We have the following scenario:
An existing .NET (Silverlight) application that uses forms authentication. 
We would like to extend the login functionality so that users that are already logged in against an Active Directory, do not need to login again when accessing the application. The application will be hosted in another environment than the Active Directory resides in. So the application does not have direct access to the Active Directory.
So, I guess the way to go is using ADFS 2.0 but we would like to have the following clarified:

1. Is it possible to implement "real single sign-on": once the user is logged in against the AD (typically by the windows login in the morning), he or she can access the application without being prompted for any kind of dialog?
2. How can it be implemented in the application: Is it "just" a matter of providing the security token to a intermediate page that validates the domain email address against the application specific list of users and then redirects the user to the front page of the application?

I have looked through the following resources

[How to Configure IIS and ADFS to Use Active Directory as a Claims Provider](http://www.davidgiard.com/2012/12/23/HowToConfigureIISAndADFSToUseActiveDirectoryAsAClaimsProvider.aspx)

[Installing ADFS 2 and Federating an Application](http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/08/13/Installing-ADFS-2-and-Federating-an-Application.aspx)

[How to install ADFS 2.0 and configure SAML for SSO (auto login/AD login integration)](http://www.thepicketts.org/2013/02/how-to-install-adfs-2-0-and-configure-saml-for-sso-auto-loginad-login-integration/)

-but I'm still not able to clarify the above.

Answer (score 0):

after digging and reading a lot I've come up with the following:

There are two common usages for the term "single sign-on":

1) Using the same identity to login to multiple apps. In other words, you have one identity, as defined by a single identity store, be it active directory, or whatever, and you use that identity across multiple applications, up to and including across company and network boundaries.

2) Automatic sign-on. This means that the combination of network, identity provider, and application come together to create a situation where the user doesn't have to provide their credentials at all, even though they are checked. This works a little bit magically through applications that are able to get and submit or test computer/network credentials. Internet Explorer can do this with ADFS, but I have been told that it requires the AD server to be in the same forest as the client.

Unfortunately, I think #2 is what you're after, and I'm pretty sure that it is not a big part or consideration of ADFS. I gather that ADFS is mostly intended to help with "federated" sign-on, not "automated" sign-on.